# How to get a smooth dimming with SSAO?

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, ssao

I implemented SSAO in my game based on the [tutorial](http://www.gamerendering.com/2009/01/14/ssao/) at gamerendering.com. But the results I get are disappointing. Instead of a smooth effect as seen in the nvidia demos, my implementation causes either squashy dark noise or results in a huge performance hit for all the blurring.

This is my scene without SSAO applied.

[image: scene simply without SSAO]

And this is how the result looks.

[image: scene with ugly SSAO]

For now I use the same code as provided in the example I linked above. How can I improve the result of the ambient occlusion shader? A lot of blurring seems to be very slow on the GPU. I would like to get a result similar to [this by Nvidia](http://www.gamerendering.com/wp-content/uploads/nvidia.jpg). How do they do that?

Comment: Hard to answer anything more than "follow the tutorial". If you are having trouble following the tutorial, there's not much we can answer here without more details.

Comment: I think I followed the tutorial correctly. After that I tweaked the parameters to improve the result. But it's far away from the results I've seen all over the web. My question isn't about the tutorial, it's about a way I can improve the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSAO is frequently implemented with noisy sampling, plus a [bilateral filter](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MANDUCHI1/Bilateral_Filtering.html) to smooth things out while preserving sharp edges.  The tutorial only mentions this in passing in the second paragraph, so perhaps you missed it:

> This SSAO term is saved to the red channel to the texture. This result must be blurred before combined with the original scene render. The blur can for example be a bilateral blur.

From your screenshots, it appears you've implemented the base SSAO effect, but without the bilateral filter.  There was a [SIGGRAPH course on bilateral filtering in graphics](http://people.csail.mit.edu/sparis/bf_course/) that you might want to check out for additional information.

Comment: I use filtering but it might be a naive approach. I just average over all pixels in a given distance. With a distance of ten or more pixels, the results are nice but the framerate drops from 60 to around 15 frame per second.

Comment: @sharethis There are definitely better ways to do filtering.  First off, you can do a 1D horizontal blur followed by a 1D vertical blur.  For a box filter or Gaussian filter this is mathematically equivalent to a 2D blur, but much cheaper.  For other types of filters it's a useful approach as well, but may introduce artifacts.  Second, you can generate SSAO at a lower resolution, like 1/2 or 1/4 of screen resolution, and blur it at that size.  That will also make the blur much cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I like the idea of lower resolution sampling. Unfortunately I have no clue how to do that yet. But maybe this is another question.